# How to restart an animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm trying to restart an animation that stops once you minimise the app then re-open it. So when I start the app fresh from Xcode, it animates fine, the genie bobs up & down... But when I close the app with the bottom button, and open it, the app returns to it's original y coordinate and then stops.

The function genie_animation works fine, like I called an NSLOG in the below active function and it worked, but the anim didn't.

I called the function in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` :

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
 {
// Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
ViewController *vc;
vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[vc genie_animation];
}
```

Then this is my code for the anim:

```
-(void)genie_animation {
CGRect frm_up = tpl_genie.frame;
frm_up.origin.y -= 4;

[UIImageView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     tpl_genie.frame = frm_up;
                 }
                 completion:nil
 ];
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new view controller every time the app becomes active? You also don't seem to put this view controller on the screen at all, so it isn't surprising that you don't see any animation.

Comment: Ok, I can solve this, but I want to know the initial value for tpl_genie.frame ?

Comment: Hi, it's 128 and 14. (X Y) Thanks.